# Benefactor badge isn't being awarded automatically

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, bounty-badges

It's been just over 24 hours since I manually awarded the bounty on [my question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51947/allow-users-to-opt-out-of-all-favorite-notifications).

This is the first bounty that I've set and awarded on Meta, but I haven't gotten the [Benefactor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/68/benefactor) badge yet. Obviously, I don't care much about the badge itself; I want to make sure the system is working properly.

I'm uncertain how isolated this is. I don't think it's a Trilogy-wide problem as it was [awarded](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/221/benefactor) once (at the time of writing) on Stack Overflow after the initial round of awardings. I checked and I'm not in the [list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/68/benefactor) on Meta (just in case the system thinks I have the badge).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted, I was not accounting for the bonus change (where you no longer get the 50 bonus)

Comment: Just got the badge now. Thanks!